How to deploy the AWS Cognito JS for browser
How does one build or acquire the AWS Cognito browser-side javascript file? I am using Cognito User Pools
on the back-end, but not any javascript frameworks on the front-end.
The goal is to build a website that leverages AWS Cognito and Cognito user pools for sign-up and log-in. AWS does not provide a distibutable javascript file for this purpose, so I am relying on this blog entry from Khoj Badami on how to build the cognito javascript file.
I've tried without success to follow the instructions on this blog entry. I illustrate the steps to build the file in what follows, making only slight changes due to the fact that my development machine is Windows, and Khoj's instructions were for Linux.
Step One: Setup workspace
On your windows development machine, start a powershell console and find a clean empty workspace directory.
$baseDir = 'C:\DEV\Whatever-you-want' # <== Localise!
cd $baseDir
new-item -type directory -path amplify-js-app -force | out-null
cd amplify-js-app
new-item -type directory -path src -force | out-null
node --version # v18.16.0
npm --version # 9.5.1
@'
{
  "name": "cognito_js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
'@ | set-content -path .\package.json

Step Two: Fetch libraries
npm install aws-amplify --prefix .
npm install webpack --prefix . --save-dev
npm install webpack-cli --prefix . --save-dev
$packageManifest = get-content -path .\package.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$packageManifest.scripts | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'build' -Value 'webpack'
$packageManifest | ConvertTo-Json | set-content -path .\package.json
@'
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
'@ | set-content -path .\webpack.config.js

Step Three: Configure/Localise
$region   = 'ap-southeast-2'         # <= Localise as required!
$pool     = 'ap-southeast-2_POOL_ID' # <= Localise as required!
$clientId = 'WEB_CLIENT_ID'          # <= Localise as required!
@"
// Importing Amplify & Auth From the AWS Amplify Lib
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: '$region',
        identityPoolRegion: '$region',
        userPoolId: '$pool',
        userPoolWebClientId: '$clientId'
    }
});

// Here we call the configure method.
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();

// Logging out the result to the console.
// This will help us to see that everything is working
// as expected
console.log(currentConfig);
"@ | set-content -path src\app.js

Step Four: Build
npm run build

When I run the build, I get the following warning. I'm not sure if this is significant.
WARNING in ./src/app.js 18:22-36
export 'Auth' (imported as 'Auth') was not found in 'aws-amplify' (possible exports: Amplify)
Step Five: Test
Create the html file and test it by loading it into a browser.
@'
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </body>
    <script src="./dist/main.bundle.js"></script> 
</html>
'@ | set-content -path .\hello.html

Open the hello.html file in Google Chrome browser and then open the javascript console
Khoj Badami's blog entry says the following should be displayed in the console ...
{
  "region": "ap-south-1",
  "identityPoolRegion": "ap-south-1",
  "userPoolId": "ap-south-1_ieXhlE_userPoolId",
  "userPoolWebClientId": "16em4vun_userPoolWebClientId",
  "Auth": {
    "region": "ap-south-1",
    "identityPoolRegion": "ap-south-1",
    "userPoolId": "ap-south-1_ieXhlE_userPoolId",
    "userPoolWebClientId": "16em4vun_userPoolWebClientId"
  }
}

... however, what I get instead is the following error message ...
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loginWith') Amplify.mjs:90
    at AmplifyClass.notifyOAuthListener (Amplify.mjs:90:48)
    at AmplifyClass.configure (Amplify.mjs:68:14)
    at Object.configure (initSingleton.mjs:52:68)
    at eval (app.js:11:57)
    at ./src/app.js (main.bundle.js:159:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.bundle.js:1163:41)
    at main.bundle.js:1203:37
    at main.bundle.js:1205:12

Clicking on the console through to the source code, the offending line of code (line 90 in Amplify.mjs) reads ...
if (!this.resourcesConfig.Auth?.Cognito.loginWith?.oauth ||

How do I fix this?

The original blog post was made for Amplify version 5.0.10 .
I am using Amplify version 6.6.2 . Over the time between these two versions, the following breaking changes where made:

The Auth class is no longer directly surfaced; and
The Amplify.configure() pass-in parameter has changed it's schema in a breaking way.

Here is how src/app.js should look
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';    

// Here we are going to put in the info we got after
// creating the user pool from the AWS Console.
Amplify.configure({
    aws_region: 'ap-southeast-2',
    aws_project_region: 'ap-southeast-2',
    aws_user_pools_id: 'ap-southeast-2_POOL_ID',
    aws_user_pools_web_client_id: 'WEB_CLIENT_ID',
    aws_mandatory_sign_in: 'enable'});    

const currentConfig = Auth.configure();

// This will help us to see that everything is working as expected
console.log(currentConfig);

